# Additive perturbation

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, robust-control

consider the following transfer functions:
$$
G(s)=\frac{1}{\tau s+1}G_0  \quad \tau_{min}<\tau<\tau_{max}
$$
show that this system equal to model with additive perturbation as follow
$$
G(s)=G_1(s)+W(s)\Delta \qquad ||\Delta||\le1
$$
$\Delta$ is perturbation and where
$$
W(s)=-\frac{r_{\tau}\tau_ms}{(1+\tau_m s)^2}\qquad G_1(s)=\frac{G_0}{(1+\tau_m s)}
$$
in this
$$
\tau_m=\frac{\tau_{max}+\tau_{min}}{2}\quad r_{\tau}=\frac{\tau_{max}-\tau_{min}}{\tau_{max}+\tau_{min}}
$$
and

Comment: @AJN   I edited the question. thank you for your attention

Comment: Is there any assumption on $G_0$ ? Like its order or if it a proper transfer function etc. ? I think that there probly exists some assumption that order of $G_0$ denominator is one more than $G_0$ numerator.

Comment: yes, $G_0$ is a proper transfer function.